# Carrierwave Direct AWS4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, carrierwave-direct

I've followed the instructions to setup carrierwave direct but get the following error.

```
<Error>
<Code>InvalidRequest</Code>
<Message>
The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.
</Message>
<RequestId>F6DF8200E7EA5DDA</RequestId>
<HostId>
nOFuJ7LTr3Sw2egpsvAtJIwhOhGIruWQbpL6vLs6i7tinvIsFbOVZcUSg2udnL8HopU/KlFvvss=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

I am able to upload when just using Carrierwave on its own. However when I use Carrierwave Direct it simple fails. My S3 bucket is in London, I don't know if this might affect it. I've been over everything again and again but can't seem to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% an answer, but by choosing London as where my S3 bucket was placed it appears to only have recent protocols and Carrierwave_direct doesn't support them. So I had to change the location of my bucket to another option. Then it worked like a dream.